# Cannot resolve symbol 'JavaPlugin' intelij

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm trying to create a minecraft plugin and I keep getting this error when I hover over `JavaPlugin`.

[Error when hover over javaplugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBla1.png)

I went into project structure > modules > dependencies > and added the spigot 1.18.2 jar. however I still get this error. Pls help.

here's what my code looks like:

```
package net.superiorcraft;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class myfirstplugin extends JavaPlugin {

}
```